# Can't get traefik to work as reverse proxy on docker swarm

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, traefik

I set up a cluster of 3x Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Stretch Lite and Docker 18.06.1-ce. Swarm is initialized and working fine so far. I read the docs on setting up traefik on docker swarm ([1](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/), [2](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#docker-swarm-mode) ) but I can't get the whoami container proxied from traefik.

Here's my stack.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker --docker.swarmMode --docker.watch
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8002:8080"

  whoami:
    image: stefanscherer/whoami
    networks:
      - proxy
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/whoami"
```

Stack is running:

```
$ docker service ls
ID              NAME                        MODE            REPLICAS    IMAGE                        PORTS
tx0npbsb3t0k    traefik_traefik             replicated      1/1         traefik:latest              *:80->80/tcp, *:443->443/tcp, *:8002->8080/tcp
7fqaew880p9p    traefik_whoami      replicated      1/1         stefanscherer/whoami:latest
```

The proxy network is set up with the overlay driver and the attachable flag.

Traefik dashboard is accessible and shows the whoami frontend and backend. But opening http://pinode1/whoami/ in the browser I get `Error 502 Bad Gateway` (with or without trailing slash).

I have traefik running and serving whoami successfully on another non-swarm machine so I wonder what's wrong in the swarm setup.